# User Profile Synchronization (Point to Local Folder for Photos)

Tags: 2010, user

I am attempting to Re-Map the Picture Field to a Local Folder that has all of our corporate employee's photos. Each employee has an image predified for their samaccountname - \sharepoint-appserver\apps\photos\samAccountName.jpg

How would I go about doing this?  I want all pictures to point to this directory rather than using ad's pic.

Any solutions/idea's would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't really use an event receiver, what you want is a [timer job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx).

If you then use that to access the user profile database (UPM User Profile Manager) will allow you get access to that, here is a good link to a similar problems solution.

Remember you will probably need Create / Read / Update/ Delete functions and you might want to check the User Profile Change Log ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms549249%28v=office.12%29.aspx ) to look for changes.

http://burcakcakiroglu.com/?p=2804

Comment: Why not create a usercontrol feature and override the profile image control?  Any reason why I would want to use the timer job instead of a feature install and just override the profile picture?

Comment: Sorry Joe, bad weather here had no internet, the timer job is a cleaner way of doing it, the user control could work yes that's if you can implement one into mysites easily. This sort of thing could be a bigger headache than required that's why i never even suggested it.